# Extracting text from cells, preserving non-ASCII characters

Tags: front-end, notebooks, string-manipulation, boxes

Consider the following setup, based on [this answer by WReach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18572/12):

```
eval = (ToString[#] &)

CellPrint[
 Cell[TextData["őúű"], "Program", 
  Evaluatable -> True,       
  CellGroupingRules -> "InputGrouping",
  CellEvaluationFunction -> eval]]
```

This will create a cell that, when evaluated, will simply output its own contents, converted to a string.  My goal is to preserve non-ASCII characters during this conversion.

Notice that with the example contents I included, I get this string as  output

```
"\[ODoubleAcute]\[UAcute]\[UDoubleAcute]"
```

This is not the same as the input, `"őúű"`.  The difference is not just in display, it's actually a different string as you can verify using `StringLength` or exporting the string to a file.  What I need to get is:

```
"őúű"
```

i.e. a string of length 3.

How can I get this?

---

EDIT:  Inspecting the cell expression shows that it does indeed contain the 39-character string `"\[ODoubleAcute]\[UAcute]\[UDoubleAcute]"`. So the key to the solution may be figuring out how to convert this to a unicode string containing those characters.

EDIT 2:  I found the following way to convert named characters in a string `str` to actual unicode characters.  But this is undocumented, I don't know where it may go wrong, and I'm sure there must be something better ...

```
First@FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`ExportPacket[Cell[str], "InputText"]]
```

Comment: Related: [How to “Copy as Unicode” from a Notebook?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1137/121)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure this answers

[You won't get this to work with a text cell](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2481/109). Your `CellEvaluationFunction` already receives a parsed string.

If you use an inline text cell you can get it to work

```
CellPrint@
 Cell[BoxData@Cell@TextData["őúű"], "Program", Evaluatable -> True, 
  CellGroupingRules -> "InputGrouping", 
  CellEvaluationFunction :> (#[[1, 1]] &)]
```

But you can only write in the inline text cell. Otherwise

```
CellPrint@
 Cell[BoxData[""], "Program", Evaluatable -> True, 
  CellGroupingRules -> "InputGrouping", 
  CellEvaluationFunction :> (FE`makePlainText@First@# &)]
```